# How do I install an earlier version of Java SDK on OSX

Tags: java, macos

I have the Java 1.8.0_45 SDK installed on OSX Yosemite (10.10.4), but because of a bug in this release I need to go back to 1.8.0_25

I have downloaded and installed the earlier version (1.8.0_25) but even after a reboot `java -version`still shows 1.8.0_45.

I don't really understand where Java resides on OSX, but how can I get my system back so it uses 1.8.0_25

Comment: Look at the System32 folder.

Comment: @RomanC I was about to ask if you were serious.... Then I look at your rep... Now I really hope that you are :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and add this to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can have multiple JRE/JDK's installed, by changing this path, you can specify which one you use each time you open a new shell.

Here is what I use in my .bashrc

```
JAVA_VERSION=7
JAVA_7_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
JAVA_8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

tmp="JAVA_${JAVA_VERSION}_HOME"
export JAVA_HOME=${!tmp}
export PATH=${!j}/bin:$PATH
```

Here, you can simply change the `7` to an `8`.

This will change the JAVA_HOME, and append the bin directory to your path for general use from the command line.

*note* you may beed to change your java home's according to the specific release versions installed on your machine.

Comment: Not quite what I asked but I can this is more flexible than my approach of just deleting the installation so marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ah found it, suprisingly easy:

```
macbook:JavaVirtualMachines paul$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
macbook:JavaVirtualMachines paul$ ls
jdk1.7.0_40.jdk jdk1.7.0_45.jdk jdk1.8.0.jdk    jdk1.8.0_05.jdk jdk1.8.0_20.jdk jdk1.8.0_25.jdk jdk1.8.0_45.jdk
macbook:JavaVirtualMachines paul$ sudo rm -fr jdk1.8.0_45
```